# Convergence in L2 (up to a constant) implies convergence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ such that $\mathbb{E} [|X_n|^2] = a_n + c$ where $a_n \to 0$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers and $c > 0$ is a constant. Then can we say anything about the convergence in probability of $X_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence of random variables $X_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})$ with the uniform measure on $[0,1]$. Well $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|^2) = \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n} + 1$ where $c = 1$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n}$ fulfill your properties. Now consider the sequence of random variables $Z_n = (-1)^n X_n$. You get that $Z_n$ have the same properties, but $Z_n$ does not converge in measure/probability to any random variable; the two candidates being $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for this counter example. Sorry, I meant to say that $X_n$ is a positive valued sequence of random variables. In that case would we have convergence in probability?

Comment: Vitali's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) tells us that in a probability space that convergence in measure is equivalent to convergence in $L^2$ if our sequence of functions are all $L^2$. The constraint you have given is that $||X_n||_2 -||X_m||_2\to 0$. This is much weaker that $||X_n- X_m||_2\to 0$